# Custom font not loading correctly in Tauri

Tags: css, custom-font, tauri

I am trying to use a custom font (Figree) in my Tauri app. The font is loading correctly for some elements, but not for others. My code is below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Window title</title>
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-tauri-drag-region id="title-bar">
      <p id="title-bar-title">Window title</p>
      <button class="title-bar-button">Minimize</button>
      <button class="title-bar-button">Maximize</button>
      <button class="title-bar-button">Close</button>
    </div>
    <h1>This is a test.</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
:root {
  font-size: 20px;
}

*, ::after, ::before {
  appearance: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Figtree" !important;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  user-select: none;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#title-bar {
  display: flex;
}

#title-bar-title {
  display: block;
  flex: 1 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.title-bar-button {
  flex: 0 0;
}

@font-face {
  font-display: block;
  font-family: "Figtree";
  src: url("/assets/Figtree[wght].woff2");
}

@font-face {
  font-display: block;
  font-family: "Figtree";
  font-style: italic;
  src: url("/assets/Figtree-Italic[wght].woff2");
}
```

My goal is to use the Figtree font for all elements in my app. However, with the above code, the `h1` element displays as expected (with the Figree font and a font weight of 700), but all other page elements that contain text do not. When removing the `!important` in the CSS code, no elements display with the Figtree font, making me wonder whether the user agent stylesheet has something to do with this.

Using the “inspect element” functionality, I have verified that the stylesheet and font files are loaded correctly. Under the “font” tab, all elements show up as having the Figtree font, but as pointed out earlier, not all actually display as this font, instead using a fallback sans-serif font.

I am using Tauri version 1.5 and version 2.0.3 of the Figtree font in WOFF2 format. My operating system is Linux Mint version 21.2.

Edit: I forgot to add this (I did not copy-paste the code), but the title bar `div` has the `data-tauri-drag-region` attribute, which makes it act like a native title bar. Could be important?

Screenshot of Tauri app:

[image: Screenshot of Tauri app window]

Comment: Can you post some screenshots? I don't seem to have the same problem with your code. I also added `font-family: Figtree` in `:root`, maybe that's why.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the resulting Tauri app. I forgot to include the `data-tauri-drag-region` attribute in my code, this could be the problem. I should try removing that etc. but it's 12.33 at night here, I'll do that tomorrow.

Comment: Also @Rob, I am aware the `link` tag doesn't need the closing slash, it's just an old habit I learned from poorly informed YT tutorials that I never bothered to change, since it doesn't cause any problems either.

Comment: Well, yeah, it doesn't cause any problems because it doesn't do anything and has no meaning in HTML. So it's completely pointless to insert it as even browsers ignore it. [It can even cause problems](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-directly-preceded-by-unquoted-attribute-values) so it's a habit you should break.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to achieve with this custom font solution?

Comment: I've gotten it to work in the end. I most likely forgot something in the source code; the code above is not copy-pasted from my project, I've retyped it since I was writing this from a different pc. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a demo project I've recreated on github with custom window and custom font, I did test it on Mac, all pieces seem to work okay. Including the Figtree font.

https://github.com/developermindsetcom/tauri-custom-font

Here's `styles.css`

```css
:root {
  font-family: Figtree;
//...

@font-face {
  font-display: block;
  font-family: "Figtree";
  src: url("/assets/fonts/Figtree-Regular.woff2");
}

@font-face {
  font-display: block;
  font-family: "Figtree";
  font-style: italic;
  src: url("/assets/fonts/Figtree-Italic.woff2");
}
```

Also set `decorations` inside `tauri.conf.json`:

```json
"windows": [
      {
        "decorations": false,
        "fullscreen": false,
        "resizable": true,
        "title": "custom-font",
        "width": 800,
        "height": 600
      }
]
```

And `plugin-window` since I'm using Tauri v2 (alpha):

```json
"plugins": {
    "window": {
      "all": false,
      "close": true,
      "hide": true,
      "show": true,
      "maximize": true,
      "minimize": true,
      "unmaximize": true,
      "unminimize": true,
      "startDragging": true
    },
...
```

Here's a little step-by-step [tutorial](https://www.developermindset.com/tauri-custom-window-and-custom-font/) I've added.

Let me know if builds and works on your Linux Mint.

Comment: Thanks for this info, I've gotten it to work in the end (see comment on my original post). I'll upvote this answer, though, because I found it very help. Side question: what's the purpose of `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased`, `-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale` and `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%` and would you recommend adding them to my project?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Font smoothing and size adjustment is done to prevent low-quality fonts from rendering with less pixelization. If you like how your fonts look without those params, then you should be good. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth